# Cloning a drive with clonezilla yields error when cloning to disk of same size

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, clone, clonezilla

I have 2 x 500 GB drives. One is out of the box new and is on a USB external mount. The other is the source drive in my laptop.

When I use *Clonezilla*, I get an error saying `The destination drive is too small`.

It's by a few bytes, so can I get around this in advanced mode using the `-icds` command ? This is a Windows 7 machine booting with *Clonezilla* Silver CD.

Comment: For the record, it's 2 sectors too small!

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with two options enabled: -icds and -k1. For some reason, Clonezilla gave me the same error with only -icds enabled.